# Posting to Facebook using customised views

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am building an iOS app that shares content on Facebook. As a requirement we cannot use the default sharing screen provided by iOS6+ because:

- We want to use customised views for sharing.
- We share links with custom actions, therefore we have to use */me/feed* OpenGraph call.

It would be optimal to ask the user for credentials once he taps on the "Post" button, but the problem with latest SDKs (> 3.1) is that, according to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/

permissions for reading and publishing must be asked in two separate instances as:

> You are now required to request read and publish permission separately (and in that order). Most likely, you will request the read permissions for personalization when the app starts and the user first logs in. Later, if appropriate, your app can request publish permissions when it intends to post data to Facebook.

and

> It is important that you do not simply attempt to call the two individual methods back-to-back to replace either of the deprecated functions.

Did someone manage to sort this issue out?

Comment: Generally, you would ask them to login with facebook when your app starts, which gives you read permissions, and then when the user hits Post, you ask for write permissions. Alternatively, if the user chose to skip login at the beginning, then I think it's OK to ask for both types of permissions sequentially when they hit Post.

Comment: @MingLi I think this is how Facebook envisions the use of their app. We don't want to bother the user with Facebook login anyway, why on earth do we want them to log in to Facebook if they may not use Facebook for sharing or have access to a Facebook account anyway?